# ArrayList content not showing while accessing from another class

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have defined ArrayList and added few data into it by one class

**Class containing ArrayList defination**

```
package practice;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Prac {
   static ArrayList<Integer> ar1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
   public static void it(){
      ar1.add(1);
      ar1.add(2);
      ar1.add(2);
      ar1.add(2);
      ar1.add(2);
      ar1.add(2);
      ar1.add(2);
      ar1.add(2);   
   }
}
public class Exet{
      public static void main(String args[]){
            Prac.it();
      }
}
```

Then i  want to see the data stored into the ArrayList by another class by Iterating it my second class is as follows

**second class**

```
package practice;
import practice.Prac;
import java.util.*;
public class StackOver {
      public static void main(String args[]){
            System.out.println(Prac.ar1.isEmpty());
                  Iterator<Integer> it=Prac.ar1.iterator();
                  while(it.hasNext()){
                        System.out.println(it.next());
                  }
      }
}
```

but when i am executing second class it is not showing anything so my question is, am i doing something unprincipled (then what is the reason) or is there any way out, a detailed explanation will help me understand it thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing first class `public class Exet{` this is a **seperate program** it have its own `main` method. and once `main` method completes all the data related to that program is removed from memory.

Then you are executing your 2nd class, which have its own `main` method and is nothing to do with anything that first class execution have done, because these are **two different programs you are executing**.

You can have as many classes as you want in your project with a `main()` method in. But, the Java Virtual Machine can only be instructed to run one of them at a time as an entry point to the program.

Comment: It fixed my problem thanks can you provide some resources so that i can understand how main method works and what are the conventions to call it

Comment: Good to hear. :) you can have a look in details [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/main-method.html#the-java-main-class) under the section **The Java Main Class** it will give you the clear idea.

Comment: @MDTALIBALAM  for any other readers i don't think so that the accepted answer would be helpful for the users to identify the exact cause of the issue occurred.

Answer (score 0):

> Declaring a method static does not mean it will be run when your class
>   is loaded.

in your first program you called the method which populates the arraylist. in the second program you never called it.

add a static block to your first program and populate your arraylist in this static block if you want it to be available to your other class or you can make a call to **"it()"** method from the static block of the first program.

when your first class is loaded your static block will be run and your arraylist would be initialized.

change your first program to the below:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> ar1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
static {
        ar1.add(1);
        ar1.add(2);
        ar1.add(2);
        ar1.add(2);
        ar1.add(2);
        ar1.add(2);
        ar1.add(2);
        ar1.add(2); 
}
```

change the scope of your arraylist so that it is available to your other class and initialize your arraylist in the static block as shown.

a simpler solution would be to call the method which initializes the arraylist in a static block of your first program as shown below:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> ar1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static {
        it();           
}
```

you can access your arraylist as follows in your other class:

> Prac.ar1

Comment: I don't want to call the method which populates the arraylist in the second class i just want the access of data stored in it through second class like i am defining the array list in the first class but i am seeing data within it through second class hope you understand what i want to do

Comment: the upper comment was for msagala

Answer (score 0):

```
package practice;
import practice.Prac;
import java.util.*;

public class StackOver {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Exet.execute(); // <-- Add this in your second class, this will run the code in Exet class.
        System.out.println(Prac.ar1.isEmpty());
        Iterator<Integer> it=Prac.ar1.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will be your main method.

```
package org.test.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Prac {

    static ArrayList<Integer> ar1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void it() {
        ar1.add(1);
        ar1.add(2);
        ar1.add(2);
        ar1.add(2);
        ar1.add(2);
        ar1.add(2);
        ar1.add(2);
        ar1.add(2);
    }
}

class Exet {
    public static void execute() { // I remove the main method in here.
        Prac.it(); // In this way, you populate the values in array using Exet Class's execute method.
    }
}
```

Try code above. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes this one is working fine but i don' want to call the definition of ArrayList in the second class.It should be defined in the first class but i want it to get visible by second class

Comment: so do you want to execute two main methods at the same time ? or maybe we can fix it by changing your Exet Class main method to a normal method?

Comment: I edited my answer, when you are using Exet.execute(), you are not literally populating it on your second class. you use the second class to call the execute method of Exet Class. That's why I think this is the only way we can do that rather than running 2 main methods at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @msagala but indirectly we are calling pract.it() method into my second class that i do not want.